# Why is srand() not being stored in my variable?

Tags: c++, variables, random, srand

This beginner's program I am trying to make is basically a program where a truly random number is generated and the "player" has to guess the number. The computer will respond "too high" or "too low" until the player guesses the right number.

I got this program idea from some website, and thought I should roll with it. This is my second program- my first being a simple I/O program.

Here is my code:

```
// BracketingSearch.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

int x = srand(time(0));
cout << x << endl;
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    cout << 1 + (rand() % 100) << endl;
}
string stall;
getline(cin, stall);
}
```

Side notes:
I don't think I need that many headers; I am still getting use to the c++ libraries.
Please critique my code as much as possible. I am eager to learn programming!
The `string stall` is just to make my console application pause for input, so I can see the results.

Thank you for everyone who can help!
-Mike

Comment: You seem to have 2 different questions: "Why is srand not being stored in my variable" and "Please critique my code as much as possible". Are you looking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)? Please clarify.

Comment: The return type of `srand` is `void`. I am surprised your compiler didn't complain about `int x = srand(time(0));`.

Comment: The function `srand()` doesn't have a return value. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/
Edit: Looks like @RSahu was faster by a couple of seconds.

Comment: Rather than `srand` and `rand` take a look into using [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Did this pass the compiler? `srand` does return void, and the compiler should not permit this value to be assigned to x.

Answer (score 4):

`srand(time(0))` seeds the random number generated by `rand()`. Its return type is `void`. void type cant be stored in an integer type variable.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm) for more information on `srand()`.

Comment: How do you recommend I store a data type of void for this program? I followed that link, and it has great advice. Thank you!

Comment: why do you need to store `srand(time(0))` in a variable? simple `srand(time(0))` would also do the job.

Comment: I tried using `rand()` throughout my program and it seems that the function is changing it's value every time I place it.

Comment: When using `srand(time(0))`, it won't let me use `cout <<` to print anything or use the `!=` and `>` operators. It appears that it's because `srand()` is a void type while `rand()` is an int data type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the program to use the minimum of headers required. Since I think this is homework, I left the original error in place, but placed the error output from gcc here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// this is a personal thing, but I avoid "using namespace std;"
// in any file, since it makes it less clear where some symbols
// came from

int main() 
{
    int x = std::srand(std::time(0)); // line 11
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        std::cout << 1 + (std::rand() % 100) << std::endl;
    }

    // Windows folklore -- you should better switch your ide to not close
    // the terminal after the program was run
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The output of `g++ -Wall foo.cpp`:

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:11:40: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         int x = std::srand(std::time(0));
                                        ^
```

Comment: Using Visual C++, here are my errors: `a value of type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"` and `initializing: cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'`